# Bootstrap 4 - navbar toggle not working on safari

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

all the navbar toggle with all the links inside works on every browser except Safari. Is there a way to fix this.

Can't get the code to display properly.

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
```

Here is a fiddle thing
https://jsfiddle.net/ceq2uagq/

Website 
http://www.barriersecurity.co.uk/

Comment: fix your code errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.barriersecurity.co.uk%2F

Comment: It works. If mean that you can not open the menu in Safari. Try Private window